# Why do we use Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)?

Tags: java, dao

I was writing a DAO file and saw it being used quite a few times but didn't get the clarity as to why we use this and what is it's purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `entityManager` wraps around a `Session` (among other things).

From the documentation of EntityManager for `unwrap`

> Return an object of the specified type to allow access to the provider-specific API. If the provider's EntityManager implementation does not support the specified class, the PersistenceException is thrown.

So in your case you *know* the entityManager has a Session and want to use it - you "unwrap it" into that class.

This is necessary as **casting** will not work